# Relation between doInBackround() and execute() method of AsyncTask (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have recently started learning android but Asynctask concept has tricked me up.

My question is how do `doInBackground(Param ...params)` and `execute(Params... params)` are related to each other. How does the `execute()` method passes its arguement to `doInBackground()` method.

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: That's more about the concept of generics.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I am no more confused in this concept, at least for now things are pretty clear.

Comment: @KishanKumar Did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes, it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are confused with `varargs` and `generics` associated with the `AsyncTask`. In order to explain it simple , I'll take a simple example:

```
    class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
      for (String item : items) {
        if (isCancelled())
          break;

        publishProgress(item);
        SystemClock.sleep(400);
      }

      return(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
      if (!isCancelled()) {
        adapter.add(item[0]);
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           .show();

      task=null;
    }
  }
```

There are generally `4` methods associated with the `AsyncTask` :

- `onPreExecute()` [optional] - to run tasks on the UI thread before starting the background thread, eg: showing a progress bar.
- `doInBackground()` [Must] - method that executes code from a background thread.
- `onProgressUpdate()` [optional] To pass data while the background thread is performing operation, eg : to pass the download percent to the user while the download operation is carried out. This is executed on the main thread.
- `onPostExecute()` [optional] This method is executed right after the `doInBackground()` method finishes the execution. eg: you can dismiss the progressbar as the download is completed.

Now coming to the generics: `<Void, String, Void>` [as in this case]

- The `doInBackground()` receives the first of three data types, ie `Void` . You can change the data type. If you have a list of URLS to be downloaded, then you can change it as a var arg of String arrays. As in this case as we do not have any info to be passed to the `doInBackground()` method, we've set it as `Void`.
- Now the `onProgressUpdate()` method will receive a varargs of the second data type. ie  `<Void, String, Void>` -> `String` . Which will be in the form of the data passed from the `doInBackground()` method.
- Now `doInBackground()` returns the 3rd data type to `onPostExecute()`, which in this case is `Void` , if you need to pass other data types you are free to do as well. So :  `<Void, String, Void>` -> `Void` in this case.

And the `execute()` method simply starts the `AsyncTask()` to have its job done:

```
AddStringTask task=new AddStringTask();
task.execute();
```

Comment: `task.execute();`. Where are the parameters OP asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Basically whenever a **class** or **subclass** extends AsyncTask<*Params1*, *Progress2*, *Result3*> 3 generic types:

- Params: The value that comes in or you pass when you call execute
- Progress: The value for progress on the execution
- Result: The product/result/value that you get from the background execution

and 4 steps:

- onPreExecute: Before you do any execution this method will be called
  first you can set a progress bar or anything that needs to be set
  before you do anything inbackground such as LongOperation().execute(SOMETHING)
- doInBackground: As the name suggests this is where the actual background task takes place using Params1
- onProgressUpdate: Again as the name suggests this is where
  the progress update notification takes place using Progress2
- onPostExecute: Again as the name suggests this is where after
  executing the task and returns the result Result3

**Sample 1:**

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
            txt.setText(result); // txt.setText(result);
            // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
            // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Starting the background Task 1:**

```
new LongOperation().execute();
```

**Sample 2:**

```
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String output = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
            }
            return output;
        }

        private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    output.append(s);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();
        }
// Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
            outputText.setText(output);
        }
    }
}
```

**Starting the background Task 2:**

```
// URL = "http://alkathirikhalid.com/message.html"
GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });
```

**Sample 3:**

```
public class PostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String> {
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
        context = params[0].first;
        String name = params[0].second;

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // http://10.0.2.2:8080/hello
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mail-portal.appspot.com/hello"); // 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
        try {
            // Add name data to request
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            }
            return "Error: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Starting the background Task 3:**

```
 new PostAsyncTask().execute(new Pair<Context, String>(this, "Some String"));
```

**Further Resource:**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: `new LongOperation().execute();`. As OP is specially interested in using params i would have thougth that you would execute the task with a lot of parameters. But you did not. Like: `new LongOperation().execute("aaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", äsdfg");`.

Comment: Sample 2
// URL = "http://alkathirikhalid.com/message.html"
GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });

Comment: Why are you giving an example with only one parameter? OP specifically asked how parameters are transferred.

Comment: Aha AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String>... new PostAsyncTask().execute(new Pair<Context, String>(this, "Some String"));

Comment: @GreenApps  As per the question how do doInBackground(Param ...params) and execute(Params... params) are ***related to each other***. How does the execute() method ***passes its arguement*** to doInBackground() method...you also can contribute your side and demonstrate the usage for params[0], params[1], params[2]... params[n]... Sample 1-3 is sufficient to demonstrate the relationship and passing of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is from AsyncTask.java [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.execute%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

`public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute(Params... params) {
        return executeOnExecutor(sDefaultExecutor, params);
    }`

It takes Variable Params and hence When you call execute method it actually calls this method.

From here all it does is `exec.execute(mFuture)
[image]

`mFuture` has already been setup in AsyncTask Constructor as below image.
[image]

So inside `mWorker call()` method you can actually see doInBackground() being called. Hope it answers your query :)